# Mobile vs desktop development framework choice

Tags: android, ios, iphone, web-applications, web-frameworks

This is a bit of a general question, but also a hard-to-Google one.

I'm creating a prototype website for a personal project, and need to decide on a web application framework to use. I know for a fact I will want to port this application to the iPhone and Android platforms in the future.

Are there any obvious choices that would minimize future headaches? (Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET, PHP, etc?)

Barring that, are there any obvious choices that I should discard immediately? (ASP.NET comes to mind as I don't see a good way to replicate that in an iOS application.)

My primary goal is minimizing the amount of architectural overhauling required to port to native apps on mobile platforms (as opposed to just running my site in a mobile browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to implement the mobile applications in native code, then you can choose any platform for web application as long as you are going to expose web services in JSON, XML and SOAP. Android, iOS and any other mobile platform supports this format. I personally prefer PHP or ASP.NET as they are easy to implement on web and the services can be easily created, exposed and secured.

Otherwise if you want to port your application using any porting tool or other frameworks that can create applications for more than one mobile platform in one shot, HTML5 - CSS - JavaScript - jQuery - AJAX will be a better choice.